# Error: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I created new .net core 2.1 project. And I created my classes like below. But, I take error in `MyRepos.cs`.

**'MyDbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'UnitOfWork'**

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{ }
```

**IUnitOfWork.cs**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork<U> where U : DbContext
{ }
```

**MyRepos.cs**

```
public class MyRepos : UnitOfWork<MyDbContext>, IMyRepos
{ }
```

**IMyRepos.cs**

```
public interface IMyRepos : IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext>
{ }
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(GetOptions())
    { }

    public static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), "myConnectionString").Options;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a parameterless constructor to `MyDbContext`, I think that should fix the issue.

That's what the `new()` constraint implies.

Comment: also maybe make options "optional" null and : base( options ?? GetOptions() ) might work

Comment: Thanks @TKharaishvili . Yes that fixed. But, I need parameters. So, I can't delete my parameters

Comment: @HasanOzdemir you don't need to delete parameters. You can have two constructors.

Comment: Yes. You're right @TKharaishvili .This fixed my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir no problem.